# Streaming live video from an IP camera in android phone

Tags: android, rtsp, lan, ip-camera

I want to create an android app which will fetch the live streaming from an IP camera connected on the local area network. How can I do it? What are the protocols and technology will be required to do this.

Comment: Ask the manufacturer of the camera. Nobody else can tell you what "protocols and technology" will be required.

Comment: e.g., ffmpeg, nginx video server